# AngularJS the function called retrieves data but does not assign it to the $scope variable

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-scope

I have a function that adds a comment to the database and then if a response is returned, the function updating the list of comments is called.

the strange thing is that when the comment is normally added from the page, the list is updated, but when it is added from the modal window, you do not want to update anymore and it is strange that the console.log (resp.data) display is full list of all comments but do not want to assign it to $scope.comment.

Controller :

```
$scope.addComment = (comment) => {
    comment.notificationID = $scope.notification._id;

    return ApiService.comment.addComment(comment)
        .then((resp) => {  
            getCommentList();
        });
};



function getCommentList() {
    let notificationID = $scope.notification._id;

    return ApiService.comment.getCommentList({ notificationID })
        .then((resp) => {
            console.log(resp.data);
            $scope.comments = resp.data;
        })
};
```

Template Ejs :

at bottom page notification.ejs

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="tab-content col-md-6">
        <div id="stream" class="tab-pane">
          1
        </div>

        <div ng-controller="NotificationController" id="comments" class="tab-pane fade in active">
          <article class="comment" ng-repeat="comment in  comments">
            <div class="circle circle--greater comment__left-side">
              B
            </div>
            <div class="comment__right-side">
              <span class="comment__author">{{comment.user}}</span>
              <span class="comment__content">{{comment.description}}
              </span>
            </div> 
          </article>

          <div class="comment__input">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="comment.description" placeholder="Napisz komentarz...">
            <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" ng-click="addComment(comment)">Dodaj</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Template Ejs at top the page (after click comment is open modal-window)

```
<div ng-controller="NotificationController" class="modal fade" id="addComment" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Dodawanie nowego komentarza</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <form novalidate name="form"> 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">Komentarz</label> 
                        <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" ng-model="comment.description"></textarea>
                    </div>  
                </form>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Zamknij</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="addComment(comment)">Dodaj</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Question is why called the same function with 1 place, she update list and with second place he download list but wont assign ?

Comment: Each `ng-controller` creates its own instance. Use a service to share data across instances

Comment: thanks, how will know the second instance that first downloaded the list?

Comment: do some reading on how to use services to share data

Comment: Modal dialogs create their own scope and then destroy that scope when the dialog is completed or cancelled. Data returned from a dialog should be resolved from the promise returned.

Answer (score 0):

You should use from

```
 window.scope = $scope;
```

in

```
  app.controller('test',function($scope,....){
   window.scope = $scope;
   .....
 })
```

with `window.scope = $scope;` you able access `$scope` to all part of controller.